# Cipher Text Program : Coding Competetion

Tags: encryption

Saurabh Bothra from TE IT wanted to have a secret private conversation with one of his juniors. But he could only talk to her via Manav Shah, his classmate, whom Saurabh did not trust!

For maintaining his privacy, Saurabh seeked help from the Hacking Guru Hardik Anvekar. Hardik taught him about ROT13 - a method used in UNIX systems for encryption. Saurabh used this idea and came up with a his own method. Saurabh taught this method to his junior when he met her personally near the lake in the campus where he could talk to her without the help of Manav.

In Saurabh’s encryption technique - Saurabh would substitue each letter of the plain text with another letter depending on the position of the first character of the key in the Alphabet series. Suppose the first character is G(7th letter in alphabet), Saurabh would then substitute the first character of the plaintext with a character succeeding it by 6. Saurabh would do this for first 7 characters after which he would use the second character of the key and substitute the futher characters in that fashion. Once all the characters of the key are used up - Saurabh will start using the first character again and encrypt the entire plaintext.

But sadly, Saurabh could only device the method but he couldn’t code it. He trusts you to write a code to print the ciphertext and not reveal his secret method to anyone.

Input Format

Number of test cases T(<=100)
Plain text and key separated by @ character.

Output Format

Ciphertext only

Sample Input

> 1  Our greatest weakness lies in giving up. The most certain way to succeed is always to try just one more time.@gaurav

Sample Output

```
Uax mxkanymn qyuehymm fcym ch xzmzex lg. Kyv dfso xzmovdi rvt oj npxxzkj oy glqusm ni nls domn ihy dfiv kzdv.
```

Comment: OK, and what is your question?

Comment: Please Provide the Code for the same

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? What reward would you expect to win from the coding competition if we win it for you, and how were you planning to share it with us?

Comment: I am not geting the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've been given a terrible specification. It includes a couple of magic numbers without explaining where they came from. I implemented it anyway for fun and got a working program, and here's what I figured out.

Given the key 'gaurav':

- Take the first letter 'g'. Its "offset" is 6 greater than 'a'. That is, `ord('g') - ord('a') == 6`.
- Use that offset value of 6 for 7 (6 + 1) letters in a row. That is, for each character in the plaintext, if it's a letter, add 6 to it (and subtract 26 if the result goes past 'z').
- *Consume one of those 7 occurrences of the 6 offset for each character in the plaintext, even if it's not used! If the character is a space of punctuation, don't add 6 to it but still count it as one of the 7 uses!*
- The next letter in the key is 'a'. That gives an offset of 0. Use it 1 (0 + 1) time.
- The next letter is 'u' with an offset of 20. Use it 21 times.
- And so on.

So your algorithm will look like:

```
O + 6 => U : #1 of 7 6s
u + 6 => a : #2 of 7 6s
r + 6 => x : #3 of 7 6s
" "        : #4 of 7 6s
g + 6 => m : #5 of 7 6s
r + 6 => x : #6 of 7 6s
e + 6 => k : #7 of 7 6s
a + 0 => a : #1 of 1 0s
t +20 => n : #1 of 21 20s
e +20 => y : #2 of 21 20s
...
and so on
```

What I'm *not* telling you how to do (it's your contest :-) ):

- Preserve case. For instance, `chr(ord('U') + 20) == 'i'`, but you don't want to translate an uppercase 'U' to a lowercase 'i'.
- Create a stream of those offsets and use one up for each character in your input stream.

Hint:

- You want to *generate* an iterator of offsets instead of creating a list of them all at once.